# Can't SSH to Amazon Lightsail server using browser-based client

Tags: ssh, amazon-lightsail

I've been able to use the browser-based SSH client without any issues until today. Now, I'm getting the following error each time I try to connect. I've tried restarting, stopping/starting, and removing/adding back the static IP.

> **CONNECTION ERROR**
>   An error occurred and we were unable to connect or stay connected to your instance. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you using DHCP on the client side that might have changed the address of your computer?  You might need to update the address allowed to connect to SSH through the security group.

Comment: No, not using DHCP or anything different. It's the same case for multiple computers I've tried. For Lightsail, there's no configuration like that; it just works out of the box when you launch the browser-based client while logged in.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" This question shows the research done and is useful to anyone else who has this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I enabled the `ufw` firewall on Ubuntu and closed my SSH session. Naturally, I was unable to SSH back in on port 22 since only ports 80 and 443 were allowed at that point.

For Lightsail, I don't think there's a way around it, unless a snapshot from one instance can be loaded onto another instance.

For AWS, you can unmount and put the volume on a new instance: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=112384

Comment: I locked myself out the same way. I created the snapshot, created a new instance from that snapshot but ran with (sudo ufw allow ssh) in launch script which fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

1. To fix it, add following 2 lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/lightsail_instance_ca.pub

CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

2. Restart

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

---

**Problem**
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

CLIENT_UNAUTHORIZED [769]

Comment: This solve my problem , 
recently I upgraded debian from debian 10 to debian 11 , and after that Iam unable to access the SSH using 'connect to ssh' from lightsail console and I got CLIENT_UNAUTHORIZED [769], and after I add what you said and restart sshd then Iam able to access the ssh using lightsail console again.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the browser-based SSH tool on lightsail web console to connect to my instance after upgrading to debian 11 (while `ssh` command from my personal machine worked fine). The line `CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` fixed it for me.

Comment: I noticed this issue started after I restored a new LightSail instance from a snapshot. Question is why did the browser SSH stop working after restore the instance from a snapshot (external SSH clients had no impact)?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen multiple times and it seems caused by incomplete setup of the server stack due to exhaustion of RAM memory... I don't know why this happens more on AWS than other clouds (even when I setup the exact same server stack).

Try to use a VM with at least 2GB memory and reinstall fresh.

Also I'm not 100% sure but I think port 22 is required for the AWS web-based Console to function regardless of changes you make to `sshd_config`... and keep in mind that the `root` user is disabled by default on AWS servers, even in Console mode, so using `sudo` is required.

On other clouds if there's any issues I can always use the Console to login as `root` and fix settings and reboot the server but this isn't supported on Amazon, so I use the default port 22 for SSH when using Amazon cloud servers. Also be sure you enable access to that port in both the Networking tab of the machine (AWS UI) and in any firewall too like UFW Firewall.

Besides all this, the Console has had general instability in the past as per [@Carlo answer](https://serverfault.com/a/866088/144798). Again, all of these challenges seem unique to Amazon...

I recommend using other clouds whenever possible lol.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after creating an Ubuntu 20 Lightsail VM then doing an in-place upgrade to Ubuntu 22 (via `sudo do-release-upgrade`). Luckily I added my own public key to the ubuntu user's authorized_keys file before the upgrade, so I was able to ssh in directly from my laptop after the upgrade completed.

The web-based SSH console, however, gave me a "CLIENT_UNAUTHORIZED [769]" error.

Examining `/var/log/auth.log` showed the following error:

```
sshd[1449]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

This keytype is apparently not supported by default on Ubuntu 22 Jammy, though it was on Ubuntu 20 Focal. Compare the two man pages...

Search for `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Search for `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/sshd_config.5.html

I then edited my server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to include the following at the bottom:

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Then after a `sudo service ssh restart`, I was able to connect as expected from AWS's web-based SSH console again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251943) that encountered the same problem.

There seems to be an issue that happens with Lightsail setups wherein the web-based SSH service stops working properly for some reason.  The advise was to [create a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/create-instances-from-snapshot.html) of the Lightsail instance to preserve the current data then create a new instance that installs an updated SSH server using user-data similar to the following:

`#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server`

It says that web-based SSH might not be possible after since they seem to be using a special SSH configuration for it.  You will need to SSH directly to the server using a SSH client.

Comment: Does Lightsail allow applying a snapshot from one instance to another instance?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same issue after I enabled ufw firewall on ubuntu 20.04 but had Installed webmin before this issue.
So I used the webmin console to enable ssh via port 22 on the ufw.